# How to do transformation between two cameras (RGB and Thermal?

Tags: camera, transformation, camera-calibration

I have two cameras including RGB (raspberry pi high quality with lens(6mm, FOV 63)) and Thermla camera (MLX90640 (FOV 110)).

Current view

[image: 1]

How to do transformation? like calibration of FOV. Images of two cameras should be exact same. Please see the expected result.

After transformation

[image: 2]

I tried OpenCV transformation, But it doesn't work well depending on different Field of view in two cameras.

Here is arrangement of cameras in hardware [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sVzn.jpg)

Comment: please show the arrangement of cameras. -- if they don't share an optical center, the mapping will never be perfect. -- there are approaches but they're comparatively expensive, both in additionally required hardware and in computational requirements. -- welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. arrangement of cameras uploaded.

Comment: in that case, you could align them to line up at some working distance (say infinity), and accept proportional misalignment on objects that aren't at that working distance. alignment is probably easiest if done physically/manually.